# Textbox Value for where Clause

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
SELECT verlog.bearerid, detail.snum 
FROM verlog 
INNER JOIN detail 
ON verlog.txnid = detail.txnid  
WHERE verlog.bearerid ='"+ TextBox1.Text +"'
```

is this the right way to obtain the value of a text box and use it in a where clause?

Comment: still not working cant seem to retrieve the data coming from the verlog.

Comment: please show the full code... it is not clear the context -- if this is C# it would not compile, if this is a stored procedure it would give an error.  What is this?

Comment: Also remember to consider SQL Injection attacks. That right there could allow people to do nasty stuff.

Comment: What happens if someone enters `1' or 1=1 --` into the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By constructing the statement in this way you open yourself up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks in which users may be able to run additional sql against your database.

You can protect against this by using parameterised sql. Then pass both the query and the parameters when executing.

```
SELECT verlog.bearerid, detail.snum 
FROM verlog 
INNER JOIN detail 
ON verlog.txnid = detail.txnid  
WHERE verlog.bearerid = @bearerid
```

Further details can be read here: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Alternatively you can use an ORM which will handle this for you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as the correct answer by pressing the tick rather than updating the question. This will help others in the future who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I seggest not to write scripts as you mentioned; that would pave the way of injection. If not using any ORM technology such as Entity framework which in turn calls for its own security issues as well, always stick into parametric ado.net queries. Look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/232854/Passing-Data-from-a-Textbox-into-a-SQL-where-Claus)